# Is there a merge conflict resolving procedure in visual studio code like PyCharm?

Tags: visual-studio-code

PyCharm has a nice procedure of resolving conflicts visually. Is there any vs code alternative available. For instance, how can I see all the files that have merge conflicts quickly?